# Authenticating 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' fails

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04

When trying to perform a `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 I am getting the below error

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                                                                                 
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,342 kB]                                                                                                          
Fetched 1,343 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                         
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. 
There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

FYI: I already tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-keyring`.

Comment: In my case apt dist-upgrade helped.

Comment: Had the same problem and this answer could help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1281412/600344

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Now I'm able to upgrade to ubuntu 20 after replacing below contents in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

Comment: I had to do this, then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-keyring` to get it to work.

Comment: What with what did you actually replace?

Comment: Replace existing content of /etc/apt/sources.list with this

Comment: This did not work at all for me but the  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-keyring made it work thanks #drice304

Comment: Had same issue with upgrade from 20.4 to 22.4 and to replace my sources with this content helped me. Thanks!